# Spring boot Jackson with Date

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, jackson

In my Spring boot application i should show a date string on html. I using this code to get a time jason:

```
spring:
  jackson:
      date-format: HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS
      joda-date-time-format: HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS
```

it can be word when i run with IDEA, but it can't work when i use maven to packet a jar and run this jar.
there is exception message :

```
beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jac
ksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframe
work.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
```

how should do to get a jason time  String?
here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <thymeleaf.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.0.0</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and my table class is that:

```
@Entity
public class TimeData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,pattern = "HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS",timezone = "GMT+8")
    private Date curingTime;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getCuringTime() {
        return curingTime;
    }

    public void setCuringTime(Date curingTime) {
        this.curingTime = curingTime;
    }
}
```

in my spring boot application i should to return a jason String with TimeData.
it can be get well run with IDEA ,but couldn't run with  jar .

Comment: the exception message complains about "name". Is this a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

This smells like a classpath issue. Your stacktrace also has nothing to do with your actual code. I think you may be pulling in incompatible versions of the same library somehow. Ensure you actually need all those dependencies and see what you can remove and try rerunning your jar.